# Index is not used when using a variable

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb

Background: Server application (C#) fetches order data from the database using the query below (simplified). I log the average time this takes and now there is a sudden increase in execution time (from 5ms to 50ms on average). So I went to check this query as a start.

The query is executed from the server app as following:

```
String ordernr = "123456789";
String sql = "SELECT * FROM MYDB.`MYTABLE` WHERE id = @id";
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 16).Value = ordernr;
    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        //reading data
    }
}
```

When I check the query in mysql , I get the following results:

```
MariaDB [MYDB]> SET @id  = '123456789';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [MYDB]> explain SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM MYDB.`MYTABLE` WHERE id  = @id ;
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | MYTABLE | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1448219 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [MYDB]> explain SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM MYDB.`MYTABLE` WHERE id  = '123456789';
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | MYTABLE | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 18      | const |    1 |       |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [MYDB]>
```

Now my question is, why is the PRIMARY index ignored when I use a variable?

I don't know if this is the reason for the drop in performance (as both queries return in 0.00 sec. in this example), but it made me frown why there is a difference. I use a prepared query with a variable in the server app too. So I want to check if this is related.

Could anyone explain this?

Comment: This is a MySQL question. You'll get the same behaviour no matter the client tool. What is the type of the `ID` column and the index definition? Are you passing a text parameter value for an integer ID perhaps? MySQL may be converting the *table* data to the parameter type instead of the opposite, thus forcing a full table scan

Comment: It is indeed a varchar field (varchar(16). In the database, as well as set in the C# code when adding the parameter). I could have added that.

Comment: Why are you using a `varchar(6)` field to store numeric keys? Apart from conversion and space problems, the sorting rules are different and `2` comes after `123456`.

Comment: Because the (order)id might contain Alphanumeric characters, not just numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index length indicates that `id` is actually a char/varchar column (`VARCHAR(16)` would be my guess).

Then, the problem is that the character set of the table or column and one of the connection don't match. Consider the following:

```
MariaDB [test]> create table t1 (id varchar(16) primary key, i int) charset latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.72 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into t1 values ('123456789',1),('987654321',2);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> set names latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> set @a='123456789';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> explain select * from t1 where id = @a;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 18      | const |    1 |       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> set names utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> set @a='123456789';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [test]> explain select * from t1 where id = @a;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You need to either alter the table, or to set the character set in the session, or use explicit conversion:

```
MariaDB [test]> explain select * from t1 where id = @a;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> explain select * from t1 where id = convert(@a using latin1);
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 18      | const |    1 |       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Converting the variable does indeed use the INDEX. Now I need to check my server config and see which character set is used there. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this would avoid the charset issue: `CAST(@a AS CHAR)`

Comment: I don't think so. Casting as `CHAR` would still be affected by the same connection charset settings: if the current charset is wrong, casting won't help; if the charset is correct, casting is not needed. `CAST(@a AS BINARY)` -- more likely.